# Google crawler can't render the page properly

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

For the past months I have been developing my own "javascript client side framework for SPA(single page application)" and I just want to know if I'm on the right track or not.

My framework works similar to meteor or ember and others but I've noticed that google bot has difficulties rendering my page. so I want to review some of the rendering techniques that I have used in my framework.

When the user navigates to a url ex. `http://mywebsite.com/profile/tomhanks` the router parses the url and finds that there is a controller listening to string `profile/[username]` so it triggers that controller and passes username as a variable to the controller, then the controller requests a new page (or overlay) with a template id and then the template is placed in the page.

But the problem is that Google bot won't bother doing all of this and only sees the empty html page. And I know this from fetch as Google in the Google Webmaster Tools.

How do other framworks do it? How come Google can fetch those contents correctly?

Comment: honestly curious: why are you developing your own framework?

Comment: a social networking, that is supposed to be really fast(js is less than 100 kb) with limited page templates that is really fast(only json is received from server) and is easy on the server side(no rendering is needed). page transition (when moving back and forth in pages)

Answer (score 0):

Google crawler can't guess what to type in the URL. To help the bot you should create a sitemap with all possible URLs so that the crawler can visit them: [Learn about sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en)

This can also be of your interest: [Making AJAX applications crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Comment: the crawlers check every link in the pages right? and the page is full of internal links, so that shouldn't be a problem. the problem is that after going to link url they won't get correct result

Comment: Please, explain correctlywhat the problem is in your question, unless you want it to be closed.

Comment: the problem is that google bot when visiting my website links can't render the page(because the result is page is being created on the client side using JavaScript) and hence only get the empty html page